# Delete /app path when i upload a file in my .net project running on docker

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core-3.1

Hi im having an issue with docker,im new with it, im trying to upload a file in an specific folder but when i do it docker automatically adds "/app" to the path direction even when im not using it. I just want to know if i can change that because i really dont need it.

```
var path = Path.Combine("D:/APPFilesManager/" + formfile.FileName.Trim().Replace(" ", "_"));
```

my path to save the file but im getting this error.

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/app/D:/APPFilesManager/01_MA641_S01_DC1_virtual.pptx'.
```

DockerFile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Buscador.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./Buscador.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Buscador.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Buscador.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Buscador.dll"]
```

Comment: Please show your Dockerfile or at least how you're running the container, ideally both.

Comment: sure there it is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already fixed it creating a volume with the path of the folder that i want to use, also created a docker-compose file like this.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        volumes:
            - D:\APPFilesManager:/test
volumes:
    test:
```

This allowed me to use it in mode code this way.

`var path = "/test/" + formfile.FileName;`